# How do I stop a modal view from disappearing when rotating on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, uikit, rotation

I'm using `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` to swap views when my iPad rotates. If I have a modal view or an alert view open when my device rotates and swaps views, the view swaps and the alert disappears and does not reappear, even if the alert is "presented" again later.

**Edit:**
I've narrowed this problem a bit. When a modal view is presented with `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`, the modal view "survives" rotations.

What can I do to fix this?

**Here is my implementation of `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`:**

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

//
//  Load an alternate view depending on the orientation
//


if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [self setView:theLandscapeView];
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(kDegreesToRadians * (-90));
    [UIView commitAnimations];      

}else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [self setView:theLandscapeView];
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768); 
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(kDegreesToRadians * (90));
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [self setView:thePortraitView];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(kDegreesToRadians * (0));
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [self setView:thePortraitView];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(kDegreesToRadians * (180));
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For now I'm working around by not swapping views, but that is not a solution...

Comment: Yes, I've also never encountered this issue, but that's simply because I only resize views on changing the orientation, rather than replacing them.  Would it be possible to present the modal page from a transparent hosting view, but have your content be in a subview of that which is switched out on change of orientation?

Comment: @BradLarson - Thank you for taking a look. I think that your suggestion would work, but it is slightly inefficient, because you need to load an extra view (controller). For now I am waiting for Apple to respond to this question and I'm manually resizing etc. I wanted to avoid that because UIImageViews don't take to that too well.

Comment: @BradLarson - The problem with wrapping things is that in deeper view hierarchies, this gets complicated really fast.

Comment: @BradLarson - I'm kinda' using both options now (invisible host and resize/move, it seems that swapping in a transparent hosting view may cause issues with multitasking and whatnot.

Comment: I've never before seen code that changes self.view out. I always look at that view as the fixed top view.. but I use a lot of IB. Anyway, part of this bug seems like a feature to me. If you switch out a view from behind a presented view the presented view should disappear as well. (Although it should not disappear forever). To avoid this I suppose you could dismiss alerts/views yourself before self.view is switched out.

Answer (score 2):

If I were solving this problem, I would do one of the following

1. Add the alternate views to a parent view, and not change the view property
2. Create a design for the views that does not require a full view swap, but rearranges or hides subelements of the view.
3. Present any modal from the root ViewController of the hierarchy

I would work very hard not to swap out the view entirely for the sake of orientation. It seems like something that will continue to present problems even after you have solved this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you swap views, you should also swap modal views I think.

For example, if you present popover controller - it'll automatically dismissed and then appeared with UI rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea: keep you main view constant, but change the subview to your portrait or landscape view. something like:

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    // Remove the current subview from the main view
    if (self.view.subviews.count) {
        [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    // Use your if-else block, but change [self setView:] for [self.view addSubview:]
}
```

So now when you create your modal, it will be linked to your controller, which now has a constant main view.

Note that I didn't test this, as I'm getting my head back into coding after two weeks off...
Good luck!